# R- my first row has # character in the column names?

Tags: r, read.table

My test file is formatted very odly.
The first rows starts with:

[image]
If i ignore the first row and import the data by using the read.table it works well but then i donot have the column names. But if i try to import the data using col.names=TRUE, it says "**more columns than column names**". I guess i can separately import the first row and the rest of data and add the first (which is the column names) to the final output file. But when i import the the first row: it completely ignores the column names and jumps to the row with 0 0 0 0.... Is it because the first row has a # character. And also because of the # character there is an extra empty column in the data.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing to do might be to just open the source file and delete that pound `#` sign.  Unless you are reading in many such files, or doing this often, in which case a code-based fix might be what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have 1000 of these files.

Comment: Then use one of the programming based solutions given below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities:

**1) process twice** Read it in as a character vector of lines, `L`, using `readLines`.  Then remove the # and read `L` using `read.table`:

```
L <- sub("#", "", readLines("myfile.dat"))
read.table(text = L, header = TRUE)
```

**2) read header separately** For smaller files the prior approach is short and should be fine but if the file is large you may not want to process it twice.  In that case, use `readLines` to read in only the header line, fix it up and then read in the rest applying the column names.

```
File <- "myfile.dat"
col.names <- scan(text = readLines(File, 1), what = "", quiet = TRUE)[-1]
read.table(File, col.names = col.names)
```

**3) pipe** Another approach is to make use of external commands:

```
File <- "myfile.dat"
cmd <- paste("sed -e 1s/.//", File)
read.table(pipe(cmd), header = TRUE)
```

On UNIX-like systems `sed` should be available.  On Windows you will need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and either ensure `sed` is on the `PATH` or else use the path to the file:

```
cmd <- paste("C:/Rtools/bin/sed -e 1s/.//", File)
read.table(pipe(cmd), header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to just do a single separate read of the first line to sniff out the column names.  Then, do a `read.table` as you were already doing, and skip the first line.

```
f <- "path/to/yourfile.csv"
con <- file(f, "r")
header <- readLines(con, n=1)
close(con)

df <- read.table(f, header=FALSE, sep = " ", skip=1)   # skip the first line
names(df) <- strsplit(header, "\\s+")[[1]][-1]         # assign column names
```

But, I don't like this approach and would rather prefer that you fix the source of your flat files to *not* include that troublesome `#` symbol.  Also, if you only need this requirement as a one time thing, you might also just edit the flat file manually to remove the `#` symbol.